# Unable to import `.tsx` files from `.ts` ones

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsx

I'm trying to import a `.tsx` component from `.ts` file like this:

*src/index.ts:*

```js
import { Icon } from './components/Icon/Icon';
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
./src/index.ts
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Icon/Icon' in '/Applications/project/src'
```

These are the import parts of the code:

*src/components/Icon/Icon.tsx:*

```js
export class Icon extends Component<Props> {
   /* component code here */
}
```

*webpack.config.js:*

```js
/* code */
resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
},
/* more code */
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: 'babel-loader',
},
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: {
                query: {
                   declaration: false,
                },
            },
         },
     ],
},
```

and the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.spec.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Can you import other components from `./components/` in `src/index.ts`?

Comment: Yes @MateiRadu, but they're all `.js`.

By the way, I can easily import it by doing this:

```typescript
// @ts-ignore
import { Icon } from './components/Icon/Icon.tsx';
```

Comment: @MatheusLima what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @debatanu TypeScript: 3.2.2